# Why are PhantomJS Page instances rendering previous pages? (using a Phantom Page pool)

Tags: node.js, phantomjs

I'm running an express sever on Heroku with a PhantomJS buildpack. It's purpose is to act as a screenshot service and capture images of urls that are sent to it. I've created a pool of page instances (using a phantomjs-node wrapper by sgentle) to speed up the rendering process when there are multiple requests:

```
var _pages = [];
for (var i = 0; i < PHANTOM_PAGE_INSTANCES; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    phantom.create(function(ph) {
      ph.createPage(function(page) {
        page.set('viewportSize',{width:1200,height:630},function(err){
          _pages[i] = page
        });
      });
    });
  })(i)
}
```

However, later in the Express callback, I've noticed that under heavy load each instance often renders the page that it had previously visited:

```
function generate_preview_image(req, res) {
  // Get a random phantom page instance:
  var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * PHANTOM_PAGE_INSTANCES);
  // Make sure it is not currently being used:
  while (_pages[index].busy === true) {
    index = Math.floor(Math.random() * PHANTOM_PAGE_INSTANCES);
  }
  _pages[index].busy = true;
  _pages[index].open(req.body.url, function(status) {
    _pages[index].render(req.url + '.png', function(err) {
        res.send({'success': true});
        _pages[index].busy = false;
    });
  });
}

app.post('/gen_image/', generate_preview_image);
```

Is it possible that the `page.open()` callback for instance "x" is being triggered by one of the other page instances before instance "x" has actually finished opening the page?

Comment: `while (_pages[index].busy === true) { index = Math.floor(Math.random() * PHANTOM_PAGE_INSTANCES); }` could result in a never-ending loop, because it blocks node.js' event loop.

Comment: Yes you're right, I modified that to a separate function and added a setTimeout to allow the other code to run